# How to make a DIV container that DOES NOT shrink/expand according to its text inside?

Tags: css, button, html, width, stylesheet

basically I want to make a button using a div container. It's a play/pause button, the symbol I use inside the button is bold "ll" for pause and the symbol "►" for play.

However when I switch the symbols with javascript inside the button. the width of the div also changes. As the symbol "►" is a little wider than the bold "ll".

So how can I make the div with a fixed width, so that the "div-box" does not shrink nor expand?

Thanks!

Comment: it does not work, I tried width:8px !important; also width:8000px !important;  They make no difference. Seems the width only depends on the text inside.

Comment: does your div have the 'display: inline' attribute set? can you post your code?

Comment: Yes I do have display inline

#theButton{
display:inline;

width:8000px !important; 
height:12px !important;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
border:1px #D7D7D7 solid;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
color:#336699;
background: #fcfcfc !important; 
vertical-align: 10px;}

Comment: Thanks, all, I figured it out. I need to use "display:inline-block" to achieve this. By the way, does anyone know the browser compatibility of this property? Is it supported by most browsers?

Thanks!

Comment: http://caniuse.com is a great resource for browser compatibility tables on just about any HTML or CSS item. Additionally, you'll want to make sure you answer your question and accept it, so that others can find your solution (and see that your question was answered) in future searches.

Comment: it's supported by most browsers, yes - except IE7 and below

Comment: Set the div width and height and add overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed, actually `display:inline-block;` works but not for all browsers. I ended up finding a good solution which is to use `<button>`, which by itself is a inline div and you can modify it's dimensions.